# Pass Value from one DataSet to another DataSet to filter row in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 table stacked at a single page,one for filtering previous year and 2nd table for the current year and i pass in the same value from the DataSet to these two table , the only difference is that i need to filter it with the year using the Tablix Properties. Right now i am filtering the Year with the hardcoded value like 2008,2009 for 2nd table. I planned to do it dynamically, so i created another DataSet (DS2) and tried to put it in the `fx(Expression) as =First(Fields!Year1.Value, "DataSet2")` in the Filter in the Value Textbox just like the diagram. but i get

```
Error as : A FilterValue for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ includes an aggregate function.  
          Aggregate functions cannot be used in dataset filters or data region filters.
```

i tried to use parameters, but it doen't return any table. any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to calculate the years relative to the date the report is run?

That would be easier as the function Value would then be something like

```
=Year(DateAdd("Year",-1,Now())
```

for -1 for last year, -2 for two years ago etc.